# How to run a Google App Script using Google API Service Library (Java)

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-api-client

By following the [Java Quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/java), I am able to create a new Google App Script project and retrieve the scriptId. Also, by referring to the [Restful API document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run), the script should be able to be executed using `Method: scripts.run`. However, I don't know how to retrieve the return value using `com.google.api.services.script.Script` in Java.

I've tried:

```
Script scriptService = getScriptService();
Script.Scripts scripts = scriptService.scripts();
Script.Scripts.Run run = scripts.run(scriptId, request);
```

and decompiled `run` function:

```
public Script.Scripts.Run run(String var1, ExecutionRequest var2) throws IOException {
    Script.Scripts.Run var3 = new Script.Scripts.Run(var1, var2);
    Script.this.initialize(var3);
    return var3;
}
```

The function doesn't return an `ExecutionResponse` object which I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the REST API documentation, calling [`script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) does not immediately return an `ExecutionResponse` object, but an [`Operation`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/script/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/script/model/Operation.html) object that may *contain* an ExecutionResponse:

```
{
  "done": boolean,

  // Union field result can be only one of the following:
  "error": {
    object(Status)
  },
  "response": object(ExecutionResponse)
  ,
  // End of list of possible types for union field result.
}
```

If we look at the [Java API Client library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/script/v1/java/latest/), we see that method [`Script.Script.run`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/script/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/script/Script.Scripts.html#run(java.lang.String,%20com.google.api.services.script.model.ExecutionRequest)) takes arguments of the script ID, and an ExecutionRequest, and then returns a Script.Script.Run request that must be `.execute()`d:

> Create a request for the method "scripts.run". This request holds the parameters needed by the script server. After setting any optional parameters, call the `AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute()` method to invoke the remote operation.

The request referred to by the quoted documentation is [`Script.Script.Run`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/script/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/script/Script.Scripts.Run.html), and has methods like `.setAccessToken()` for additional configuration, and several execution methods like `.execute()` and `.executeMedia()` to actually submit the execution request and return the Operation.